# How to access website hosted on IIS, from remote computer?

Tags: iis

I hosted a **website on IIS**, running on **port 81**. I can access it on the server machine from http://localhost:81/test.aspx.

I also can establish a remote desktop connection to the server, using its ip adress **server-ip**.

Now I want to access the web site using my PC (or any other PC). However, I type type http://server-ip:81/test.aspx on my web browser and the page is not loaded.

I've already **opened port 81**, by adding a new inbound rule to the server's windows firewall. The exception for World Wide Web Services (HTTP) is also ticked on. I even shut down the firewall entirely, but I still can't access the web site remotely.

Can somebody tell what the problem may be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any intermediate network device (router, firewall) possible?

Comment: @Hugo are you able to telnet to the site?

Comment: Can you access the site on the server using it's ip instead of localhost?

Comment: @AndersBornholm i can access my site with ip address on my pc only not on another pc

Comment: Could it be blocked in the network? (physical firewall, router, switch?). Can you telnet to port 81 from another PC?